# How do I prevent connection resets upon pulling the ethernet cable?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, ethernet, windows-networking

In Windows, when you pull out (trip over it) a network cable, then the connections get reset.

If you do the same on a Linux box or if you put a switch between PC and router and then pull the cable router-switch, then connections don't get reset if you put in the cable fast enough (thanks to TCPs retransmission).

Suppose I am downloading a file with Firefox; how do I prevent Windows from resetting the TCP connection automatically if the ethernet cable is unplugged during the download? My receptacle is broken and my cat always manages to pull out the LAN cable

Comment: Program the mouse to play with the cat?

Comment: Use your WiFi ?

Comment: Show us some code... how can we possibly answer this question?

Comment: There is no code... open Firefox, start a huge download, pull the network cable and put it in again after a couple of seconds. The download will be either messed up by Firefox or if you're lucky it is resumable.

Comment: @user1933738, If there is no code, then you should have asked the question on [su].  [so] is for programming questions; [su] is for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

That may depend on TCP implementation on Windows. Create your own reliable protocol over UDP. And if you want TCP connections, use gateway where cat won't come. So that you can communicate over UDP between your machine and gateway, gateway will in turn make your proxy over TCP to outside world.

Comment: It's not about my own programs, its about general using of the computer - downloads, IRC, movie streams

Comment: Yep, u can do is have UDP connection from your system to some outside gateway, then implement in gateway to create TCP connections.

Comment: You mean, something like a proxy? Actually no bad idea - but there has to be another way which doesn't need another machine to act as gateway

Comment: But its happening due to TCP in Windows, so you don't have any other option

Comment: You can't modify TCP in windows, you can do is create your own protocol over UDP. Please go ahead and buy other machine for making gateway.